# Storing superclass with inheritance JOINED strategy (Hibernate migration)

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have migrated from Hibernate 4.2.2 to 5.1.2 and now I have a problem storing superclass with **@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)**.

My Promotion entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "promotion")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "promotion_type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@XmlRootElement
public class Promotion implements Serializable {…
…
…
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "promotion_type", nullable = false, length = 17)
protected String promotionType;
…
…
}
```

One of the extended classes is PromotionEvent:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "promotion_event")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "promotion_id")
@DiscriminatorValue("event")
@XmlRootElement
public class PromotionEvent extends Promotion {
…
…
}
```

In Hibernate 4.2.2 all was working, but now with Hibernate 5.1.2 when a promotion is stored I get the following exception:
**ERROR pool-2-thread-2 SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions - Parameter index out of range (16 > number of parameters, which is 15).**

With the insert:
insert into promotion (amount, client_id, description, end_datetime, event_end_datetime, event_start_datetime, hide_amount_at_ticket, name, percentage, promotion_type, requires_pda_alert, short_name, show_amount_original_at_ticket, start_datetime, state, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'event', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

So, seems that is trying to insert de **@DisciminatorValue** of PromotionEvent in the assigned **@DiscriminatorColumn**, but **@DisicriminatorColumn** is **@Basic** and then persisted. So, here is the problem.
But, why in Hibernate 4.x this was not happening?.

I can see that it works if I make

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "promotion_type", nullable = false, insertable=false, length = 17)
protected String promotionType;
```

That’s to say, **insertable=false**, then it works and **@DiscriminatorValue** is inserted in promotion_type.

Moreover, if I remove **@DiscriminatorColumn** from Promotion, it seems that all is working, but in this case I do not know how Hibernate knows the class type (with JOINED strategy I guess).

- Should it be recommended to put insertable=false?.
- Should it be better remove **@DiscriminatorColumn** if all it’s working?.
- Can not be **@DiscriminatorColumn** a **@Basic** and insertable attribute?,
  so why in H4.2.2 there was no problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Discriminator values should go into their own column, not reusing some field column (unless you put insertable,updatable as false on the field).

Comment: Thank you Neil. So maybe there was a bug in Hibernate 4.2.2